# How create a module that sanitize a given model column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I using this [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) for sanitizing my model.

But I'd like to create a module that sanitize any column given as:

`sanitize :name, on: :product`

I'm looking for some metaprogramming, but I still didn't get anything:

```
class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__+1
   def #{column}=(value)
       #{column} = Sanitize.clean(value)
    end
  RUBY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module ColumnSanitizer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def sanitize(*args)
      args.each do |attribute|
        class_eval <<-RUBY
          def #{attribute}=(value)
            super Sanitize.clean(value)
          end  
        RUBY
      end
    end
  end
end

class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ColumnSanitizer
  sanitize :name
end
```